# <tbody> glitch in PHP Simple HTML DOM parser

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to scrape some data of a webshop (also running XAMPP 1.7.2 with PHP5.3.0), and I'm running into problems with `<tbody>` tag. The structure of the table is, essentialy (details aren't really that important):

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <!--text here-->
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!--text here-->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, I'm trying to get to the `<tbody>` section by using code:

```
$element = $html->find('tbody',0)->innertext;
```

It doesn't throw any errors, it just prints nothing out when I try to echo it. I've tested the code on other elements, `<thead>`, `<table>`, even something like `<span class="price">` and they all work fine (ofcourse, removing ",0" fails the code). They all give their correct sections. Outertext ditto. But it all fails on `<tbody>`.

Now, I've skimmed through the Parser, but I'm not sure I can figure it out. I've noticed that `<thead>` isn't even mentioned, but it works fine. *shrug*

I guess I could try and do child navigation, but that seems to glitch as well. I've just tried running:

```
$el = $html->find('table',0);
$el2 = $el->children(2);
echo $el2->outertext;
```

and no dice. Tried replacing `children` with `first_child` and 2 with 1, and still no dice. Funny, though, if I try `->find` instead of `children`, it works perfectly.

I'm pretty confident I could find a work-around the whole thing, but this behaviour seems odd enough to post here. My curious mind is happy for all the help it can get.

Answer (score 31):

in simple_html_dom.php file comment or remove line #396

```
// if ($m[1]==='tbody') continue;
```

Comment: FYI: In version `1.11` (Rev. 184) this code is at line `629`.

Comment: this should mentioned in the documentation `>: (`

Comment: In version 1.5 (Revision 196) the code is located at line 695

Comment: In version 1.5 (Revision 210) the code is at line `701`

Comment: In version 1.5 (Revision X) the code is at line Ctrl+F "if ($m[1]==='tbody') continue;"

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug report for this issue here:
http://sourceforge.net/p/simplehtmldom/bugs/79/

It is still open at the time of this writing.  There is an alternative fix if you do not wish to modify the source code, for example in a loop to find `<tr>`'s

```
<?php
  // The *BROKEN* way to find the <tr>'s 
  // below the <tbody> below the <table id="foo">
  foreach($dom->find('tbl#foo tbody tr') as $tr) {
    /* you will get nothing */
  }
```

You can instead selectively check the parent tag name while iterating *all* `<tr>`'s like so:

```
<?php
  // A workaround to find the <tr>'s 
  // below the <tbody> below the <table id="foo">
  foreach($dom->find('tbl#foo tr') as $tr) { // note the lack of tbody selector
    /* you will get all trs, but let's only work with ones with the parent
       of a tbody! */
    if($tr->parent->tag == 'tbody') { // our workaround
      /* this part will work as you would expect the above broken code to work */
    }
  }
```

Also note, a slightly unrelated issue that I ran into, that Chrome and FF inspectors will correct tag soup regarding`<tbody>` and `<thead>`.  Be careful -- only look at the actual source -- stay away from the DOM inspectors if you run into unexplainable issues.

Comment: You saved my night man. I don't know why you don't take any hit but without change helper file, your solution is best one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `tbody` is coming from some javascript execution. I was facing the same problem with a span tag. Later I found that, if any html code is getting into the page via jquery/any other javascript execution then in that case `simple_html_dom` simply fails.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that tbody is really is there. Many browsers will add a tbody to tables in the inspect panel even though they are not present in the response.